# Create Delta<TSTructuralType> out of a JSON Payload?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am working with AspNetCore.Odata 7 beta, but basically the question applies to any MVC/Web API OData Server environment.

For some requirement, I cannot just use Delta as an argument like here

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(int key, Delta<Car> delta)
```

I need it to be a JObject (which works) but from the JObject I must create a Delta.
I have been looking into ODataMessageWriter, however, that has quite some dependencies and complexity. Did anybody solve this riddle already? Or just know how to do it?

Thanks!

This is a try to get it. However, the OdataSerializerContext seems to be a total spoiler to create a Delta

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(int key, [FromBody] JToken jOb)
    {
        var feature = Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpContextExtensions.ODataFeature(HttpContext);
        var path = feature.Path;
        var model = feature.Model;
        var context = new ODataDeserializerContext
        {
            Path = path,
            Model = model,
            Request = Request,
            ResourceType = typeof(Car),
            ResourceEdmType = new Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmEntityTypeReference(new Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmEntityType("Odata7Test.Models", "Car"), false)
        };

        var dlt = (Delta)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Delta<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Car)));
        var delta = default(Delta<Car>);


        try
        {
            delta = await DeltaCopyUtil.CopyEntityToDelta<Car>(dlt, jOb, context);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Error at Patch {0}", ex);
        }

         public static async Task<Delta<T>> CopyEntityToDelta<T>(Delta delta, JToken jOb, ODataDeserializerContext context) where T: class      
var memStream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(memStream));
await jOb.WriteToAsync(writer);
await writer.FlushAsync();
memStream.Position = 0;

var message = new ODataMessageWrapper(memStream) ;
ODataMessageReader r = new ODataMessageReader((IODataRequestMessage)message);
var lst = ODataInputFormatterFactory.Create();
var myFmt = lst.FirstOrDefault(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes.Contains("application/json"));
var oDataResourceSerializer = new ODataResourceDeserializer(myFmt.DeserializerProvider);        

var obj = oDataResourceSerializer.Read(r, context.ResourceType, context);

return ( Delta < T > )obj;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the built in ASP.NET Core JsonPatchDocument feature, which can be combined with the ODataController PATCH verb. This is what I need, and I can live with the usage of a different serializer being used, (thus, not using the EDMModel) and the client must comply to IETF RFC 6901 which is quite different to an OData patch.

That would be:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(int key, [FromBody] JSonPatchDocument<Car> delta)
```

But I needed something to persist the JSON and rebuilt the object on another place.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(int key, [FromBody] JToken deltaObj2) 
    {
        var jc = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Converters.JsonPatchDocumentConverter();
        var mem = new MemoryStream();
        var jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(mem));
        deltaObj2.WriteTo(jw);
        jw.Flush();
        mem.Position = 0;
        var jt = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(mem));

        var deltaObj = (JsonPatchDocument)jc.ReadJson(jt, typeof(JsonPatchDocument), new Car(), new JsonSerializer());

        var origCar = products.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == key);
        deltaObj.ApplyTo(origCar);
        TryValidateModel(origCar);


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState.SelectMany(s => s.Value.Errors.Select(x => x.Exception.Message)));
        }
        return Updated(origCar);
    }
```